# js - remove array from nested arrays upon condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data structure like this:

```
var data = [
 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ]
];
```

Specifically, I'm interested in whether the value of the second item in each inner-most array is `0` or not. If that value is zero, I want to remove the entire array that harbors that value.

Based on the conventional approach for removing things from arrays seen here: [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array) I attempted the following:

```js
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    var thisArray = data[j][k];
    if (thisArray[1] == 0) {
      data[j].splice(k, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

However, this seemed to remove my whole data, as nothing even appeared in my console log -- not even undefined.

### Question

How does one remove an entire array based on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will throw an error `thisArray is undefined` because

- Inside variable `k` loop, you have removed the item on `data[j]` variable if it matches the condition. So the length of `data[j]` will be decreased once you remove the item from `data[j]`.
- And you have looped k from `0 ~ 3`, so if one item is removed from `data[j]`, its' length will be 3 (it means `data[j][2]` will be undefined.)

So you will get that error. It is needed to include the handler for `undefined` error part as follows.

```js
const data = [
 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ]
];

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      var thisArray = data[j][k];
      if (thisArray && thisArray[1] == 0) {
        data[j].splice(k,1);
        k --;
      }
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

Or simply, it can be done using `Array.map` and `Array.filter`.

```js
const data = [
 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ]
];

const output = data.map((item) => item.filter(subItem => subItem[1]));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a map and filter the inner item based on the item in index 1

```js
var data = [
 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ],

 [
   [0,0,4],
   [0,0,4],
   [0,1,4],
   [0,1,4]
 ]
];

console.log(data.map(item=>item.filter(x=>x[1]!=0)));
```